# "system reserved" windows partition showed on ubuntu 12.04. Not installed using wubi

Tags: partitioning, windows

windows "system reserved" can be mounted on ubuntu

```
"system reserved" windows partition showed on nauilus ubuntu 12.04. No any other problems.
I've
     sda1 system reserved
     sda2 windows partition
     sda3 ubuntu partition
     sda4 extended partition
          sda5 ntfs part
          sda6 ntfs part


This is my fstab.

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc                                       /proc        proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid         0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=917d1cad-a914-47ee-a9e2-4e3d2025285a  /            ext2  errors=remount-ro           0  1  
/dev/sda2                                  /media/sda2  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,umask=000  0  0  
/dev/sda5                                  /media/sda5  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,umask=000  0  0  
/dev/sda6                                  /media/sda6  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,umask=000  0  0  


pls hlp...
The output when  df -h used is
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        30G  3.6G   25G  13% /
udev            983M  4.0K  983M   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  904K  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            990M  684K  989M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2        30G  8.5G   22G  29% /media/sda2
/dev/sda5       100G   89M  100G   1% /media/sda5
/dev/sda6       139G   91M  138G   1% /media/sda6
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Make `sda1` disappear from Ubuntu? Can you show us the output of `df -h`?

Comment: updated the output. hlp me pls... @MariosZindilis

Comment: Again. What are you trying to do? Hide it? Delete it?

Comment: just want to hide it @ObsessiveFOSS

Comment: See my answer and if it helps, please use the checkmark to its left to mark it as accepted for other users to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system reserverd partition is used mainly for a system to restore Windows to factory defaults. There is no reason to hide it. Please press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/95-hide-ntfs.rules
```

in the window, paste:

```
# 95-hide-ntfs.rules
# /dev/sda1 System_Reserved as hidden partition
# in /etc/udev/rules.d
##################################################

ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"
KERNEL=="loop*|ram*", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"

##################################################

# Partition sda1 hide from gnome
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"

##################################################

LABEL="hide_partitions_end"
```

and use File-> Save. Reboot, and see if it helps.

If not, continue below.

Press Alt+F2 again and type:

```
gksudo leafpad /usr/share/hal/fdi/policy/10osvendor/20-storage-methods.fdi
```

and press Enter.
Find *exactly* these lines(Ctrl+F and careful eyes will be useful):

```
<match key="volume.fstype" string_outof="ntfs;vfat">
<match key="volume.label" string="RECOVERY">
<merge key="volume.ignore" type="bool">true</merge>
</match>
```

and replace them with :

```
 <match key="volume.fstype" string_outof="ntfs;vfat">
<!-- Win7 ships some desktop with a System_Reserved partition -->
<match key="volume.label" string="System Reserved">
<merge key="volume.ignore" type="bool">true</merge>
</match>
<!-- Win ships some desktop with a recovery partition -->
<match key="volume.label" string="RECOVERY">
<merge key="volume.ignore" type="bool">true</merge>
</match>
```

Save and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu & Linux.

In answer to your question 'windows "system reserved" can be mounted on ubuntu' because you now have full access & control over your computer.

You can do whatever you want, this is not an error or a bug, it's a bonus.

You could try and hide the partition using the other answer, or just leave it alone.

Comment: Is  this experienced by me only?                                 11.10 doesn't gave me such a thing @Fernhill Linux Project

Comment: You could take the time to specify how to hide it.